# Comment code with /**/?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

I'm using visual studio 2010 , (with resharper installed if it helps) :

is there any shortcut of commenting a code via `/* lalala */` and not via `//lalala` ?

I already know that `CTRL K C` comment a code but it comments it with `//`

Is there anyway of commenting a code via `/**/` ?

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C `?

Comment: @Niang have you read my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `ReSharper | Edit | Comment with block comment` which makes exactly what you need. 
Default shortcut for this - `Ctrl+Shift+/`

If you would like to uncomment it, put the caret on any place in the comment and hit `Ctrl+Shift+/` once again. The same behavior is available for `ReSharper | Edit | Comment with line comment` (`Ctrl+Alt+/`) as well.

Comment: `(ctrl shift .)` in my pc

Answer (score 0):

If you only select lalala and then hit CTRL K + C, it will uncomment lalala with /* */ (for example when lalala is a parameter in a function, just double click it and hit CTRL K+C.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in resharper : 
you can add :

[image]